Vectorizing complex householder transformations
I'm currently trying to implement a routine for getting a given hermitian matrix $H$ in tridiagonal form. So far I've written a function "housev" which calculates the corresponding Householdermatrix $P$ for a given column-vector $x$ and then "tridi" which explicitly multiplies $P$ with $H$ to get to tridiagonal form. Here are the functions:
function P = housev(x)
%Calculates unitary Householder-matrix for a given (column-)vector x
%such that Px = |x|*e1

%Size of x and setting first component
n = length(x); x1 = x(1);

%Initializing e1
e1 = zeros(n,1);
e1(1) = 1;

%angle and phase of x1
theta = angle(x1); 
phase = exp(1i*theta);

%Calculates normalized Householder-Vektor u 
u = x + norm(x)*phase*e1;
u = u / norm(u);
%Sets Householder matrix P
P = -exp(-1i*theta)*(eye(n) - 2 * (u * u'));
end

function [T, U] = tridi(H)
%Calculates a unitarily equivalent matrix T and unitary matrix U for a 
%given Hermitian matrix H, such that U*H*U' = T and T is of tridiagonal
%form.

%Setting size and starting point of iteration
n = size(H,1); T = H; U = eye(n);

%Loop over the first n-2 columns of H (the last two columns don't need 
%to be changed for tridiagonalization)

for k = 1 : n-2
    %Householdertransformation on column-vector H(k+1:end,k)
    x = T(k+1:end,k);
    P = housev(x);
    
    %Updating T and U (P doesn't act on the first k columns of T and U)
     T(k+1:end,k:end) = P * T(k+1:end,k:end);
     T(:,k+1:end) = T(:,k+1:end) * P';
     
     U(:,k+1:end) = U(:,k+1:end) * P';
end

However I'm trying to vectorise the above matrix multiplication for performance such that only the main diagonal alf and the secondary diagonal bet is stored (T is going to be a symmetric tridiagonal matrix). The main idea is to reduce storage and incorporate that:

I know that in every iteration the upper kxk-blockmatrix is tridiagonal, so the zeros don't need to be explicitly calculated
In every iteration the value of bet(k) is known - it's just the norm of H(k+1:end,k), which has been calculated earlier, so it doesn't need to be calculated again.

But I've been struggling with implementing such a vectorization, since calculating the diagonal elements every step requires the rest of the matrix to be stored too. How can I do better than just multiplying these matrices?
Edit:
For context: I'm trying to implement the eigenvalue decomposition for small hermitian matrices (5x5 or 9x9). The main idea is to transform the given matrix to a real symmetric tridiagonal matrix and then use the QR-algorithm to solve for eigenvectors and eigenvalues.
For my test data set the QR-Algorithm needs 5.51s (compared to matlabs 2.39s for the entire decomposition without calculating the tridiagonalization first), but getting the matrix into tridiagonal form requires 23.49s. I need to find a way to significantly lower the computation time without just using the matlab function hess.m.

Matlab is really optimized for standard matrix operations, so I suspect that you would do better if, rather than storing the diagonal and secondary diagonal as vectors, you store the entirety of T as a sparse matrix

@BenGrossmann I'm mostly working with 5x5 or 9x9 matrices. Do you reckon working with sparse matrices is useful in this case? I for some reason always believed that using sparse matrices is just a good idea for large matrices, but it probably doesn't really matter if your matrices are small or large as long as they have many zeros? Also using sparse matrices doesn't really complement the fact that T is symmetric.

Ah, I see. In that case, I'm not sure there's any practical benefit to storing the non-zero entries like that, even if there is that repeated secondary diagonal

Something that might save some speed: rather than computing the actual householder matrix $P$, you instead implement the product $PT$ as $-e^{-i\theta}T + (2 e^{-i\theta }u)u'T$. Again, though, that would be more of an optimization for larger matrices

If you really wanted to see some kind of computational savings as a result of this alf-bet scheme, you'd have to program things at a lower level (perhaps in C or C++).
